# SSDT Connection error while connecting SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I am trying to deploy cube project on SSDT I get the following errors:

> [Severity Code    Description Project File Line
>   Error: The project could not be deployed to the 'CAD_DB_RND2' server because of the following connectivity problems :
>   A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.
>   To verify or update the name of the target server, right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, select Project Properties, click on the Deployment tab, and then enter the name of the server

I provide the correct server name, but I still get the same issue. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Could be permissions issue

Comment: what type of permission issue could u tell me.

Comment: Account permissions to the server, check user credential permissions

Comment: for account permission I am giving as a window authentication(service account)

Comment: Do u have Software installed in the destination server ? There is useful information in this blog http://www.msbiguide.com/ssas-error-a-connection-cannot-be-made-ensure-the-server-is-running/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 First We should go in SQL Server Configuration Manager and check there 
 SQL Server Analysis Server and SQL Server Browser is running or not if it is 
 not running we cant start this services, in my case i did not installed SQL 
 Server Analysis Service I installed and again i started service now it is 
  working for me.
```